# хочу сохранить расширение для google chrome на localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, chrome-extension, localstorage, extension

написал код на JavaScript для выбора элемента и его изменения. Хочу сохранить значения на localStorage, чтобы при перезагрузке измененный элемент оставался таким же, но не смог разобраться что да как.
content.js :

```
document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
   let value = prompt('enter value')
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement,
        text = target.textContent || target.innerText;   
        target.textContent= value;

}, false);
```

Comment: Для расширений используется [chrome.storage](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/storage/) а не localstorage. Вам надо 1. сохранить в него для каждого изменения 3 вещи: url страницы, [полный xpath селектор](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661818/javascript-get-xpath-of-a-node) элемента и изменённый текст.  2. при заходе на страницу если есть её url в строе попытаться найти элемент по селектору и, если нашли, то поменять текст. А если не нашли, то контент сайта поменялся и из стора можно удалять.

Comment: спасибо, исправил. Только возникла одна проблема. некоторые элементы не меняются. В чём может быть причина? может какая-нибудь защита?(имею в виду стринги и цифры)